# My whole's power is great

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> Own my prefix to give you happiness;
>   Take on my infix to give you stress;
>   My suffix means to hesitate;
>   But my whole's power is great.

What am I?

*Note: edited first two lines for clarity*

**Hint 1:**

> The prefix, infix, and suffix are all between 2 and 4 letters long (inclusive).

Comment: I thought of two possibilities, but neither seems to fit perfectly: rot13(nfcunyg naq onpxfgbc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I got it now.

> **petroleum**

---

> ⋅ Owning a **pet** gives you happiness.
>  ⋅ Taking on a **role** gives you stress.
>  ⋅ **um** means to hesitate.

**Second Answer:**

Better than my first answer but not the intended solution (given the hint):

> **momentum**

---

> ⋅ Having a **moment** to yourself gives you happiness
>  ⋅ an **omen** (or men) - can give you stress
>  ⋅ **um** means to hesitate

**Original Answer:**

Probably not what you're thinking of but I found this...

> [Magnetopause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetopause)

---

> ⋅ **Magnet** is sometimes a toy which can give you happiness
>  ⋅ A **net** upon you would likely cause stress
>  ⋅ **Pause** means to hesitate

Comment: Added a hint in response.

Comment: Your suffix is now correct! Not quite the other two.

Comment: Third time's a charm! You're good at these, and nice persistence!